# How to fetch all data of solr which contains 40k rows into csv?

Tags: python-3.x, solr

```
import pandas as pd
import pysolr
solrcon = pysolr.Solr('...', timeout=10)
results = solrcon.search('*:*')
docs = pd.DataFrame(results.docs)
docs
```

But only able to fetch 10 rows or max limit is 100 rows . How to fetch all rows ? I am using pysolr version 3.8.1

Comment: Solr uses the concept of pagination to return results in batches. The parameters in Solr that you need to pass to Solr to configure how many documents you want and where to start are `start` and `rows` (https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_0/common-query-parameters.html#common-query-parameters). You'll need to find out how to set those parameters in the module that you are using.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`rows`](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_7/common-query-parameters.html#rows-parameter) parameter :

> You can use the **rows** parameter to paginate results from a query. The
>   parameter specifies the maximum number of documents from the complete
>   result set that Solr should return to the client at one time.
>
> The default value is 10. That is, by default, Solr returns 10
>   documents at a time in response to a query.

Passing additional options to Solr using pysolr, using `fl` as well for the example (list of fields to include in the response) because you might need to restrict this list to keep a decent response time :

```
results = solrcon.search('*:*', **{
    'rows': 100000,
    'fl': 'id, title, score' 
})
```

Comment: don't forget to disable your highlighter if you set one up by default. This saves a lot of time when exporting more than a few rows :)